# Block an IP on Linux without the use of iptables

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to temporarily block all traffic from a single ip address to my host (Ubuntu 10.10, 2.6.35). Normally I'd use iptables but that package is not installed, and while I have root on this box, installing packages is out of the question.

Comment: Are you sure that iptables isn't installed? Maybe it's just not in your path.

Comment: `dpkg -l` says it's not installed and `find / -name "iptables"` comes up empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it would suffice to block the *return* packets from your host back to the IP in question, you could null route their /32:

```
# ip route add prohibit w.x.y.z/32
```

Inbound traffic will still arrive, but the three-way handshake on TCP connections will not complete, so any new inbound connection (and indeed existing connections) will be rendered useless.

Comment: How do I undo this?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I expect `ip route delete ...` would do it...

Comment: I found it, it's `ip route del...`

Answer (score 0):

What services do you want block? If it's just http you can do that in a .htaccess file, too. Another option is an entry in /etc/hosts.deny, see the manpage for that file.

Comment: The service is a custom one running over TCP. Will adding an entry to hosts.deny kill existing connections?

Comment: no it won't kill existing connections.  Nor AFAIK will it work unless the custom service is linked with the TCP wrappers libraries.

Comment: I think that existing connections are not touched (I cannot promise tho). You need to edit inetd.conf to use the tcpd wrapper for that service.

Comment: @ott _if_ it's running out of inetd - many services don't, or can't.